# No such column error when replacing comma in integer field for percentage calculation

Tags: sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I'm having trouble calculating a percentage from integer columns in two tables in SQLite. My employeetrained and employeetotal data are both integers, but one has commas. I'm using REPLACE to take care of that and create a new column with an alias, but I can't seem to use that alias for my calculation; I'm getting an error `-- Result: no such column: trainedint` Below is my data:

TRAINED table

| id | name | employeetrained |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01331 | Cyberdyne Systems | 41,877 |
| 18774 | Nakatomi Corporation | 35,411 |
| 93571 | Tyrell Corporation | 84,000 |

CORPORATIONS table

| id | name | employeetotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01331 | Cyberdyne Systems | 48872 |
| 18774 | Nakatomi Corporation | 94547 |
| 93571 | Tyrell Corporation | 247440 |

And my query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "trainedpercent" AS SELECT trained.id, trained.employeetrained, corporations.employees, corporations.name,
             REPLACE(employeetrained, ',', '') AS trainedint,
            ((trainedint/employees)*100.0) AS TrainedPercent
FROM trained
INNER JOIN corporations
ON trained.id = corporations.id
ORDER BY TrainedPercent
```

Comment: You can't use a derived column in the same select list. Repeat `REPLACE(employeetrained, ',', '')`again: `((REPLACE(employeetrained, ',', '')/employees)*100.0) AS TrainedPercent`

Comment: Thanks, it allowed me to run the query and create the table, but for some reason all I'm getting in the new percent column is zeros.

Comment: Thanks @forpas - can you add as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Change the position of 100: `(100.0*REPLACE(employeetrained, ',', '')/employees*100.0) AS TrainedPercent`

Comment: It's fine. This question has been asked and answered many times before.